# Postman 'get new access token' returns whole doctype html of page instead of access token

Tags: oauth-2.0, postman, access-token

When i try to generate new access token with Postman, I have some trouble. I fill out all my auth information and use 'Authenticate using browser'. From there on i click 'Get new access token'. This sends me to the browser where i login. It gives me a simple success page with the URL containing the access token.

However the success popup on postman then inputs the whole success body (complete template from  etc as token. instead of the actual token.

copying over the access token into postman also does not work as this doesn't save properly, it needs to actual be through the browser.

anyone familiar with this problem?

edit: Exact same settings work for all other colleagues.

[image]